# Integrate material web components into angular library

Tags: angular, material-design, web-component, angular-library

I'm creating an angular library so I can reuse common components across multiple applications.
We want to create a library to use Material Design Web Components, so we can create components that can be used outside of angular if need be.

We set up the library as well as a demo application. I can successfully import `MWC` into the demo and use them fine. If I duplicate the same process for the library, the library can't find the `scss` file inside of the node_modules folder and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want components that can be used outside of Angular, you cannot use Angular to create them. You would need to create the web components using just javascript or with a tool like StencilJS. So therefore you would import the MDC Web library into that, not into Angular, and when you use them in Angular you would import your web component library which would include the MDC Web library.

Comment: @G.Tranter MDC is made to be used as a platform agnostic component library. So we wanted to use parts of MDC in our platform agnostic library, but add some of our own css changes. I can do this no problem in a regular angular app. But for some reason it wont work in an angular library, even though i followed the same steps i did in the non-library version.

Comment: I'm aware of MDC - I am using it as the base for a platform-agnostic web component library built using StencilJS. Maybe you could elaborate on what specifically "doesn't work."